# Troubleshooting PO705 code on 1996 Nissan pick-up truck 2.4 liter engine

Tags: engine, nissan, truck

I took my Nissan pick-up truck to the smog station, and this code appeared. This made it fail the smog test. What can I do to fix the problem?

Comment: P0705 is a transmission range switch/park neutral switch code. Could be a wiring issue a relay, ECM or switch failure. Is this an automatic transmission?